# Polynomial $P(x,y)$ with $\inf_{\mathbb{R}^2} P=0$, but without any point where $P=0$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, supremum-and-infimum

Recently I've came across such problem: give a polynomial $P(x,y)$, with $\inf_{\mathbb{R}^2} P=0$, but there is no point on the plane where $P=0$. I couldn't solve it after a day, and seriously doubt whether such a function exists, however its source claims that there is. Is that really possible?

Comment: Is this in the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, or could it perhaps be over the rationals?

Comment: The real plane.

Comment: I edited "$in f(P)$ to $\inf f(P)$, as that seems to be the more common notation. Nice question, by the way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

$P(x,y)=(1-xy)^2+x^2$ has this property. Clearly $P>0$ and also the sequence $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,n)$ shows that $\inf P=0$.

Comment: Very nice example.

Comment: Thanks! Did you hear about the answer before or created it now?

Comment: I read about it somewhere before --- I'm not sure where exactly. If I recall correctly it is a counter-example to the claim that $\text{im } P(x,y)$ is closed.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: sorry, but what is $im$?

Comment: Sorry. The image of the real plane under a polynomial in two variables. I suppose one would think it would be closed.