# Example of polynomial $p(x,y)$ that does not reach its infimum

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Polynomial $P(x,y)$ with $\inf_{\mathbb{R}^2} P=0$, but without any point where $P=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279497/polynomial-px-y-with-inf-mathbbr2-p-0-but-without-any-point-where)

How can I build example of polynomial $p(x,y)$ that does not reach its infimum?

Comment: Can you find an example of a one-variable polynomial that doesn't reach its infimum?

Comment: That question was asked a couple of days ago. Maybe someone can find it?
One possibility is $P(x,y)=(1-xy)^2 +x^2$.

Comment: [Polynomial $P(x,y)$ with $\inf\_{\mathbb{R}^2} P=0$, but without any point where $P=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279497/polynomial-px-y-with-inf-mathbbr2-p-0-but-without-any-point-where) gives a nice answer.